# print abstract in biblatex-chicago bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-chicago

I am able to print an abstract in my bibliography if I rename the field in my `.bib` "Annote" and call `biblatex-chicago` with `\usepackage[annotation]{biblatex-chicago}`

How can I print the "Abstract" field in the bibliography without renaming it? Is it something like

```
\let\Abstract\Annote
```

Would that be something to put in a `.bst` file in my working directory?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\def\cms@choose{cms}
\usepackage[notes,isbn=false,url=false,backend=biber,annotation]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\bibliography{../currentBib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\let\cite\footcite
\date{\today}
\title{annotated bib}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Biber you can just map the `abstract` field to the `annotation` field with

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=abstract]
      \step[fieldset=annotation, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

This only works if you don't already use the `annotation` field for other purposes.

---

Or you go with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\par\nobreak \vskip \bibitemsep #1}
\renewbibmacro*{entrytail}{% From reading.bbx, for annotated bibliography
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@annotation}%
    {\usebibmacro{annotation}%
     \newunit\newblock}%
    {}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{abstract}%
  \newunit\newblock}
```

which just prints the `abstract` field after the `annotation` field. That means you can use both fields simultaneously.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[notes,isbn=false,url=false,backend=biber,annotation]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\par\nobreak \vskip \bibitemsep #1}
\renewbibmacro*{entrytail}{% From reading.bbx, for annotated bibliography
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@annotation}%
    {\usebibmacro{annotation}%
     \newunit\newblock}%
    {}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{abstract}%
  \newunit\newblock}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: references with <code>abstract</code> and <code>annotation</code>]